# How to list files in windows with full pathname

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to list files in a directory at sub-folder level

I'm doing

```
dir /s path
```

[image: example output]

Is there any way possible that we can list the file full path name like below

```
M:\admin_view\GemBalancing\AllocationAndBalancing\AnalysisAndDesign\SUC\Report\BalancingSurveyReportSUCS.doc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the `/B` option:

> /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

---

Using:

```
dir /S /B path
```

You will get the folder recursively with the full path everywhere.

---

Using:

```
dir /S /B /A:-D path
```

You will get a list of files only from all directories within.

---

You can read the other options and what they do by using the command:

```
dir /?
```

Comment: Also if you don't need directories in your listing you could add `/A:-D` to exclude those and only show actual files. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You need a batch file for that ... 
The following code should work

@echo off

Cd\

For /r %%a in (*) do (

Echo %%a>>all_files.txt

)